# Unable to establish connection after one node offline in TDengine cluster

Tags: tdengine

I have a TDengine cluster with 4 nodes, node1 to node4. In configuration file: /etc/taos/taos.cfg, I set two master nodes, fristEP node1, secondEP node2. In order to make sure that when node1 is down, node2 will become the master nodes, the cluster will keep working.

But when I stop taosd in node1, the cluster is down, what is the reason, why node2 cannot work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node2 cannot work as expected because you only have one mnode configured in TDengine.

In your configuration file: /etc/taos/taos.cfg, set numOfMnodes from 1 to 2 and node 2 will work once node1 is offline.

```
numOfMnodes 2
```